React Native app won't connect to server through Xcode
I'm not really sure how to fix this error. Any help would be appreciated. Happy to answer any questions!
I've created a very simple app using React Native to get heart rate from Apple Health and I am trying to run it on my iPhone. I am running it through Xcode. I have tried connecting my iPhone via wired connection to my Mac and also wirelessly. I've confirmed that both devices are on the same Wi-Fi. I've tried resetting both my Mac and my iPhone, but have had no luck. If anyone has experience with this error, any help would be appreciated!
nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C5:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection
refused]

nw_endpoint_flow_failed_with_error [C5 10.0.0.34:8097 in_progress
socket-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface:
en0[802.11], ipv4, ipv6, dns, uses wifi)] already failing, returning

nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke [C5] Client called
nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection

TCP Conn 0x3013fe760 Failed : error 0:61 [61]

nw_connection_copy_connected_local_endpoint_block_invoke [C5] Client
called nw_connection_copy_connected_local_endpoint on unconnected
nw_connection

nw_connection_copy_connected_remote_endpoint_block_invoke [C5] Client
called nw_connection_copy_connected_remote_endpoint on unconnected
nw_connection

Bridgeless mode is enabled

Unbalanced calls start/end for tag 20

Unbalanced calls start/end for tag 19

Running "MyHealthApp" with
{"rootTag":1,"initialProps":{"concurrentRoot":true},"fabric":true}


You need to configure the metro bundler. Shake the device, then select "Configure bundler", and in the dialog that pops up, enter the IP address of the network both devices are on.
